# Clearing an <input type=file>

Tags: input, hta, input-type-file

I'm writing an HTA and want the user to be able to easily be able to select a .txt file using a browser. This .txt file will be read line by line and read into an array. So, I'm using the `<input type=file name="ListFile">`, which gives me the browse function, and does what I need it to...

But I need to be able to clear the text box for the `<input type=file name="ListFile">` when user selects another method, I have setup, to input the data.

The reason I need it to clear is to prevent user error/mistakes. I currently have it setup to clear the manual entry text box when they use the browse option, but can't get it to work the other way around.

I have tried the following (which works on the regular text boxes)

```
Document.getElementByID("ListFile").value = ""
Document.getElementByID("ListFile").reset()
Docuemnt.getElementByID("ListFile").innerHTMl = ""
ListFile.Value = ""
```

None of these clear the text box.

Comment: You must call reset() for the form

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you aren't able to modify the selected file in a file input field.

There is a workaround to reset it - you can clone the file input, and replace the input with the cloned input.  It may be easier in your situation to just show / hide the inputs based on the user's selection.

For example, you can have a set of radio buttons for the user to select the input method - then show the appropriate field depending on what radio button they select.

If you absolutely must reset the file input, you can either use jQuery's `.clone()` method, or manually create a new dom element, copy over all properties, insert it after the original file input, then remove the original.

Comment: Thanks Sam Dufel... you gave me an idea. 

Created a span that creates the <input type=file> on Window_onLoad

Span Code:
    <span id="BrowseFile"></span>

Window_onLoad Code:
    BrowseFile.innerHTML = "<input type=file name=" & Chr(34) & "ListFile" & Chr(34) & " size=" & Chr(34) & "30" & Chr(34) & "> "

I then Copy this to another Sub that runs when they select the manual data entry option. Basically clearing the span and recreating the input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sam Dufel... you gave me an idea.

Created a span that creates the  on Window_onLoad

Span Code:

Window_onLoad Code: 
    BrowseFile.innerHTML = " "

I then Copy this to another Sub that runs when they select the manual data entry option. Basically clearing the span and recreating the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of a file input type, as that would introduce a security vulnerability. Instead, just replace the file input with a new one. Instead of `$('#file').val('')`, do this:

```
 $('#file').replaceWith('<input name="ListFile" type="file" id="file"/>');
```

Even better would be to clone a copy of the original version and store it in memory. When you need to replace it, just used the cloned copy, and again clone it. So, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var empty_input = $('#file').clone();

    $('#the-form').on('change', '#file', function(el) {
        $('#the-form').submit(); // assuming the target is a hidden iframe
        $(this).replaceWith(empty_input.clone());
    });
})
```

Note that I'm using the delegated version with [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so the event will still work on the new input right after it's replaced.